# ¿Como hacer un programa en C que te de 10 números aleatorios en un intervalo cualquiera (a establecer por el usuario)?

Tags: c++, c

[image: Este es el ejercicio pedido]

He hecho esto pero no funciona, salen números consecutivos y tardan mucho en salir, ya que antes salía todo el rato el mismo numero pero le puse una restricción para que no pasara y no se como arreglarlo. No se que más decir, lo necesito para clase el martes que viene y no se como funciona :(

```
// Bloque de includes de las librerias externas
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

/* Prototipos de las funciones */
short aleat (short n, short m);

/*Función generar numeros aleatorios*/
short aleat (short n, short m)
{
    short y;
    int x;
    
srand(time(NULL));
x = rand();

y = ((x * (m-n))/(RAND_MAX)) + n;

return y;
}

// PROGRAMA PRINCIPAL
int main()
{
short i, n, m, y, t;
cout << "<Este programa calcula 10 numeros aleatorios dentro de un intervalo concreto establecido por ti." << endl;

cout << "\n\tIntroduce el intervalo, el primer numero y el ultimo separados por un espacio: ";
cin>> n >> m;
cout << endl;

t = -1;
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    y = aleat(n,m);
    if (y != t)
    {
        cout << " " << y;
    }
    else
    {
        i--;
    }
    t = y;
}
system ("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Probando tu código solo tienes un problema de tamaños, la función `rand()` retorna un número demasiado grande, que al multiplicarlo por el númeo del rango, la variable entera no soporta el valor y por eso esta dando error tú código, lo unico que tendrías que hacer es este cambio:

```
/*Función generar numeros aleatorios*/
int aleat (short r1, short r2)
{
    int y;
    double x;

        x = rand();

        y = (x * (r2-r1)) / RAND_MAX + r1;

        return y;
}

// PROGRAMA PRINCIPAL
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    short i, n, m, y, t;
    cout << "Calcular 10 numeros aleatorios" << endl;

    cout << "\nRango inferior: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "\nRango superior: ";
    cin >> m;

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        cout << aleat(n,m) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!! :D